# python thread pool size

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a threadpool and want to show the number of currently running workers:

```
threadPool = ThreadPool(poolSize)
...
threadPool._processes
```

_processes always shows 2, even if my poolSize is much bigger. I also know that there are more running workers because the processingtime decreases when I increase the poolSize.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't the size of your pool. `_processes` is just the `processes` value you passed into the initializer (or the number of cpus, if `processes` is None). With

```
ThreadPool()._processes
```

you created a *new* pool, initialized to the number of cpus on your system. I will now use my psychic powers to predict that you have 2 cpus. If you want the size of your pool, check your pool instead of creating a new one

```
threadPool = ThreadPool(poolSize)
...
threadPool._processes
```

Comment: How do I check the size of the current pool? i.e. the actual used size. Not poolSize. (Assuming that poolSize is set to 100 and only 50 are needed)

Comment: Oh, you want how many are in-use at any given time? I'm not sure that's tracked. I'll take a peek.

Comment: I don't see a good way to do it. You could implement a process wide counter that each worker increments and decrements.